# Can I interpolate a time-series without changing the meaning of the data?

Tags: interpolation, time-series, neural-networks

I am planning do data augmentation through interpolation to aid the small dataset size available for my neural network to train on. How can I interpolate a time-series without changing its meaning?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

**Jäger, Sebastian and Allhorn, Arndt and Bießmann, Felix.** *"A Benchmark for Data Imputation Methods"*. Frontiers in Big Data. Vol 4, 2021. DOI: 10.3389/fdata.2021.693674. url (accessed Oct 2022): https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fdata.2021.693674

In general, data imputation is an approximation to fill in missing data. It obviously changes the meaning of the observations. Whether the change in meaning is significant depends on a lot of factors, including how significant the attribute missing values is in impacting your measurement.